# Is there a way to get all the possible rearrangements of a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I want to create a function that rearranges the elements of a list.

For example the list [1,2,3] will produce:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,3]
[2,3,1]
[3,1,2]
[3,2,1]
```

The order isn't important. 
If I write this list comprehension:

```
[[a,b,c] | a <- l, b <- l, c <- l, a /= b, a /= c, b /= c]
```

It works (where l is the desired list). Problem is I want to do this for an undefined number of list elements

Comment: Sounds like you want the [permutations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. The `Data.List` module has a [**`permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) function to generate all permutations. This does not only work on three or more elements, but it does not use an `Eq` typeconstraint. If a list contains two items that are equal, then you can still consider it a different permutation when we swap the two.

We can furthermore implement such function ourself. We can first make a helper function that is given a list and returns a list of 2-tuples where the first item contains the value we "picked", and the second item a list of remaining elements:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick [] = []
pick (x:xs) = (x, xs) : map prep (pick xs)
    where prep (y, ys) = (y, x:ys)
```

For example:

```
Prelude> pick [1,4,2,5]
[(1,[4,2,5]),(4,[1,2,5]),(2,[1,4,5]),(5,[1,4,2])]
```

Next we can use recursion to each time pick an element, and recurse on the remaining elements:

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [ p : ps | (p, ys) <- pick xs, ps <- perms ys ]
```

This then yields:

```
Prelude> perms [1,4,2,5]
[[1,4,2,5],[1,4,5,2],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,5,4],[1,5,4,2],[1,5,2,4],[4,1,2,5],[4,1,5,2],[4,2,1,5],[4,2,5,1],[4,5,1,2],[4,5,2,1],[2,1,4,5],[2,1,5,4],[2,4,1,5],[2,4,5,1],[2,5,1,4],[2,5,4,1],[5,1,4,2],[5,1,2,4],[5,4,1,2],[5,4,2,1],[5,2,1,4],[5,2,4,1]]
```